# Firebase Emulator: using PubSub in Functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to run my Firebase functions locally through the emulator. I have built a architecture where chains of processes are invoked by PubSub events. When trying to invoke these events, the emulator logs give me this:

```
Sorry, we cannot connect to Cloud Services without a project ID. You may specify one with an environment variable named "GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT".
```

I am running the emulators with `--project {projectID}`. Also I am constructing my PubSub events like this:

`const pubsub = new PubSub({ projectId: getRealtimeDatabase().app.options.projectId })`

I am using package `"@google-cloud/pubsub": "^0.22.2"`, and I am importing PubSub like `import { PubSub } from '@google-cloud/pubsub';`

What do I have to do to make PubSub invoke new events? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turned out `getRealtimeDatabase().app.options.projectId` was undefined. I retrieved my projectId elsewhere. With the correct projectId, the code above works.